# Number of unpaired $x$ and $y$ samples needed to determine $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, sampling, decidability

This is a question from an exam on deep learning that I took not so long ago, and I'd like to know the answer.

### The Setting

---

There is a Gaussian distribution from which we sample $x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ values, but what we observe is $y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, where $y = A x$. We have an oracle that takes as input a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and returns $n$ different $x$ values sampled from the Gaussian and $n$ $y$ values corresponding to the $x$ values, but they are unpaired (meaning that if we label the $x, y$ values as

$$\begin{array}{c}
x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\\
y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}
\end{array}$$

there is some permutation $\pi$ such that for all $i$ we have $y_{i}=Ax_{\pi\left(i\right)}$.

### The Question

---

What is the minimal number $n$ that we need to give to the oracle, in order to determine $A$ (prove your answer). If it isn't possible with any finite (or even infinite) number of samples - prove it. Are the cases where $A$ is invertible different from the case where it isn't?

### My Attempt

---

My initial gut feeling was that it's impossible, but then I had the following Idea.

Clearly, if we had two **paired** samples $\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right),\left(x_{2},y_{2}\right)$ we could determine $A$ easily. But since they are unpaired, what we could maybe do is choose $n=3$ and go over all different permutations, using the first two pairs to determine $A$ and check if it fits the 3rd pair. However, I am not sure if this is correct, as perhaps I could find two permutations yielding different $A$'s.

I wasn't able to prove this nor find a counter-example

Comment: Another way to phrase the question: what is the minimum $n$ such that there is only one $P$ for which the linear system (in the next comment) has a solution for $z$, where $P$ is some $2n \times 2n$ permutation matrix that preserves ordering of pairs (i.e. $y_{i,2}$ always follows $y_{i,1}$ in $Pr$).

Comment: $$
Qz=Pr \\
Q \equiv \begin{bmatrix} x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\ x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\end{bmatrix}_{2n\times 4}, \quad z =\begin{bmatrix} A_{1,1} \\ A_{1,2} \\ A_{2,1} \\ A_{2,2} \end{bmatrix}_{4 \times 1}, \quad r \equiv \begin{bmatrix} y_{1,1} \\ y_{1,2} \\ y_{2,1} \\ y_{2,2} \\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}_{2n \times 1}
$$
$n$ must be at least 3, since if $Q$ is invertible for $n=2$, then we can potentially get different $z = Q^{-1} Pr$ for each $P$

Comment: Exam in what course? Knowing what mathematical background is expected from the reader is useful information

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It's a "custom course" in my university about deep learning. I'd say we're expected to know Linear Algebra, Calculus and basic+ Probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sampling from the Gaussian distribution, I feel it ends up being a trick question where the answer is that we can't even guarantee that we'll get any linearly independent samples.

But even if we get samples $x_1,...,x_n$ that span $\mathbb R^2$, we can't always uniquely determine $A$. For this, let $R_\alpha$ be the matrix that clockwise rotates a point by $\alpha$ degrees.

Now define $x_i=R_{360/n}^{i-1} \pmatrix{0\\1}$, and $y_i:=x_i$. Then for each $k\in\{0,...,n-1\}$ the matrix $R_{360/n}^{k}$ is a possible solution for some permutation $P$.

More generally, this works for any matrix $A$ with $A^k=I$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

---

If $A$ has rank 1, the points $y_1,...,y_n$ lie on a 1-dimensional subspace. That is, after choosing a suitable base, we can write $x_1,..,x_n\in\mathbb R^2, y_1,...,y_n\in\mathbb R$ and $A=(a,b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

(More specifically, the $y_i$ would have as second component 0, so we omit it)

So, the solutions are
$$
\{a,b\in\mathbb R\mid \pmatrix{x_1^T\\\vdots\\ x_n^T} \pmatrix{a\\b} =P\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\ y_n} \land P \text{ is a permutation matrix} \}
$$

Now, the Rouché–Capelli theorem tells us that to end up with exactly one solution, all permutations of $\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\ y_n}$ need to be linearly independent to the columns of $\pmatrix{x_1^T\\\vdots\\ x_n^T}$.

So, one can get a generic counterexample by choosing $\pmatrix{y_1\\\vdots\\ y_n}$ and the columns of $\pmatrix{x_1^T\\\vdots\\ x_n^T}$ such that  all are permutations of one another. One can generalize the Rouché–Capelli theorem to matrix equations to obtain a similar criterion for generic $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$.

To make it concrete, let the first column of $\pmatrix{x_1^T\\\vdots\\ x_n^T}$ be $\pmatrix{1\\\vdots\\n}$, and the second $\pmatrix{2\\1\\3\\4\\\vdots\\n}$, that is the first column, but the first and second elements have been permuted.

Now, if $y_i=\pmatrix{i\\0}$, then $A$ can e.g. either be $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ or $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$.

---

Finally, if the rank of $A$ is 0, then if we get samples $x_1,...,x_n$ that span $\mathbb R^2$, then for any $n\ge 2$ we can uniquely determine that $A=0$.